# Running optimization in parallel

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing

I've ran in parallel optimization using SciPy.

```
def optimize(f):
    return opt.fmin_powell(runner, param, args=(f,f), disp=0)

f = ['1','2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

p = Pool(processes=8)
async_ret = p.map(optimize,f,chunksize=1)
result = async_ret.get()
p.terminate()
```

When the optimizations are done, I am getting the error message in return:

```
 result = async_ret.get()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It looks the issue is with map when the list is over. Could anybody point out what is going on and how I might fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: When the optimizations are done, I am getting the error message in return:

```
result = async_ret.get()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

You are trying to call `.get()` from a `list` object assuming `async_ret` is a `pool.AsyncResult`.

> **Python » 3.6.1 Documentation: [multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult)**:
>   **class multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult**
>   The class of the result returned by Pool.apply_async() and Pool.map_async().

`p.map(` doesn't return `pool.AsyncResult`.
Do a `print(async_ret)` and you will see what you get.